# following function is giving segmentation fault on strncpy, can someone explain why this segmentation fault occurs

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
IFNAMSIZ = 16

static STATUS_CODE __bind(int sock_fd, const char *interface)
    {

            struct sockaddr sock_addr;
            memset(&sock_addr, '\0', sizeof(sock_addr));
            strncpy(sock_addr.sa_data, interface, IFNAMSIZ);
            sock_addr.sa_family = AF_PACKET;

            if (bind(sock_fd, &sock_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0) {
                    EPRINT("bind failed: %s", strerror(errno));
                    return FAILURE;
            }
        return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: because `sock_addr.sa_data` is not an str ?

Comment: Check the size of  `sock_addr.sa_data`

Comment: @Stargateur It should be a char array

Comment: The use of an actual `struct sockaddr` seems a bit suspicious, here.

Answer (score 0):

> can someone explain why this segmentation fault occurs

On Linux, your code could have stack buffer overflow here:

```
strncpy(sock_addr.sa_data, interface, IFNAMSIZ);
```

assuming `IFNAMSIZ = 16`, because `sizeof(sa_data) == 14`. However, this is exceedingly unlikely to cause `SIGSEGV` *in* `strncpy` -- there is plenty of other data on the stack.

A much more likely cause of a crash is that `interface` that you passed in is `NULL`. That should be trivially visible by compiling your program with debug info (usually `-g` flag) and running it under debugger.